# How to Change Date Format yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

When I display date from phpMyadmin to webpage with this code.

date format is showing y-m-d 
and how to change this in d-m-y

```
<?php echo $row['dob']; ?>
```

Comment: See [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: where i see this and how to change

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tablename
```

Comment: $originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
i use this code but its showing 12-31-1969

Comment: This is a better answer, the date string should be formatted when output by MySQL *not* have to be re-processed by PHP after selection.